# Como sumar valores de un objeto que esta dentro de varios arreglos? VueJS

Tags: vue.js

Tengo un array donde dentro tengo 2 objetos y dentro de estos tengo otro array y dentro de este tengo otro array de detalles y ahi es donde tengo los objetos con los valores a sumar, si pongo un ejemplo seria algo asi

```
    "tshit": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "selectRequi": []
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "cotizaciones": [
                {
                    "Bodega": "xxxx",
                    "CodigoProv": "000000",
                    "IdProv": 102,
                    "Iva": 8,
                    "RazonSocial": "xxxxxxx",
                    "SubTotal": 00.00,
                    "Iva": 00,
                    "Total": 00.00,
                    "details": [
                        {
                            "Cantidad": 4,
                            "Concepto": "ABRAZADERAS P/MUELLE 3/4 X 3\" X 18",
                            "​​​IdProd": "A000",
                            "​​​IdUnidad": "P",
                            "​​​Precio": "15.23",
                            "​ReqID": 4041
                        },
                        {
                            "Cantidad": 4,
                            "Concepto": "ABRASADERA P/MUELLE 3/4 x 3 x 18",
                            "​​​IdProd": "I174",
                            "​​​IdUnidad": "P",
                            "​​​Precio": "50.33",
                            "​​​ReqID": 4041
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Bodega": "xxxx",
                    "CodigoProv": "000000",
                    "IdProv": 102,
                    "Iva": 8,
                    "RazonSocial": "xxxxxxx",
                    "SubTotal": 00.00,
                    "Iva": 00,
                    "Total": 00.00,
                    "details": [
                        {
                            "Cantidad": 4,
                            "Concepto": "ABRAZADERAS P/MUELLE 3/4 X 3\" X 18",
                            "​​​IdProd": "A000",
                            "​​​IdUnidad": "P",
                            "​​​Precio": "15.23",
                            "​ReqID": 4041
                        },
                        {
                            "Cantidad": 4,
                            "Concepto": "ABRASADERA P/MUELLE 3/4 x 3 x 18",
                            "​​​IdProd": "I174",
                            "​​​IdUnidad": "P",
                            "​​​Precio": "50.33",
                            "​​​ReqID": 4041
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

aqui es donde me he quedado sin ideas la verdad, este formato lo hice porque dentro de la app web hice un drag and drop y tenia que estar ligado de alguna manera por un grupo, estoy desarrollando con VueJS, hago un

```
<col v-for="child in item.details"></col>
```

para asignar los detalles a una tabla, pero hasta aqui he dejado, tambien dejo mi codigo

```
                  <div>
                  <v-card elevation="3">
                    <v-responsive>
                      <v-col
                        v-for="(item, i) in tshit[1].cotizaciones"
                        :key="i"
                      >
                        <v-card-text>
                          <v-card style="border-radius: 5px">
                            <div class="titulo_flex">
                              <div class="titulo_tool">
                                <v-toolbar
                                  class="mb-2"
                                  color="#031727"
                                  dark
                                  dense
                                  style="border-radius: 5px"
                                >
                                  <v-toolbar-title>
                                    <div style="display: flex">
                                      <div
                                        style="
                                          flex: 1;
                                          margin-left: 35px;
                                        "
                                      >
                                        Razon Social:
                                        {{ item.RazonSocial }}
                                      </div>
                                      <div
                                        style="
                                          flex: 1;
                                          margin-left: 35px;
                                        "
                                      >
                                        Iva: {{ item.Iva }}
                                      </div>
                                      <div
                                        style="
                                          flex: 1;
                                          margin-left: 35px;
                                        "
                                      >
                                        Bodega: {{ item.Bodega }}
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </v-toolbar-title>
                                </v-toolbar>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tablareq">
                              <v-simple-table dense>
                                <template v-slot:default>
                                  <thead>
                                    <div
                                      style="
                                        display: flex;
                                        margin-left: 18px;
                                        text-align: center;
                                      "
                                    >
                                      <div style="flex: 1">Codigo</div>
                                      <div style="flex: 1">
                                        Descripcion
                                      </div>
                                      <div style="flex: 1">
                                        Cantidad
                                      </div>
                                      <div style="flex: 1">Unidad</div>
                                      <div style="flex: 1">Precio</div>
                                    </div>
                                  </thead>
                                  <v-spacer><hr /></v-spacer>
                                  <tbody id="dragTable">
                                    <draggable
                                      tag="ul"
                                      :list="item.details"
                                      group="tshit"
                                    >
                                      <div
                                        v-for="child in item.details"
                                        :key="child.IdProd"
                                        class="tabla_drag1"
                                        id="requisicionesitems"
                                      >
                                        <div style="flex: 1">
                                          {{ child.IdProd }}
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="flex: 1">
                                          {{ child.Concepto }}
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="flex: 1">
                                          {{ child.Cantidad }}
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="flex: 1">
                                          {{ child.IdUnidad }}
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="flex: 1">
                                          <v-text-field
                                            prefix="$"
                                            v-model="child.Precio"
                                            dense
                                          ></v-text-field>
                                          <!-- {{ child.Precio }} -->
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </draggable>
                                  </tbody>
                                </template>
                              </v-simple-table>
                            </div>
                          </v-card>
                          <div style="display: flex">
                            <div style="display: flex">
                              <div style="flex: 1; margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 5px;">
                                <v-text-field
                                  label="SubTotal"
                                  prefix="$"
                                  solo
                                  readonly
                                  v-model="item.subtotal"
                                  dense
                                ></v-text-field>
                              </div>
                              <div style="flex: 1; margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 5px;">
                                <v-text-field
                                  label="Iva"
                                  prefix="$"
                                  solo
                                  readonly
                                  v-model="item.neto"
                                  dense
                                ></v-text-field>
                              </div>
                              <div style="flex: 1; margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 5px;">
                                <v-text-field
                                  label="Total"
                                  prefix="$"
                                  solo
                                  readonly
                                  v-model="item.total"
                                  dense
                                ></v-text-field>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="btndelete">
                              <v-dialog
                                transition="dialog-bottom-transition"
                                max-width="1000"
                              >
                                <template
                                  v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }"
                                >
                                  <v-btn
                                    color="#6B0101"
                                    dark
                                    v-bind="attrs"
                                    v-on="on"
                                    >Eliminar
                                    <v-icon right dark>
                                      fa-minus-circle
                                    </v-icon></v-btn
                                  >
                                </template>
                                <template v-slot:default="dialog">
                                  <v-card>
                                    <v-toolbar color="warning" dark
                                      >Alerta pelotudo
                                      conchetumare</v-toolbar
                                    >
                                    <v-card-text>
                                      <div class="text-h2 pa-12">
                                        Deseas eliminar esta cotizacion?
                                      </div>
                                    </v-card-text>
                                    <v-card-actions class="justify-end">
                                      <v-btn
                                        text
                                        @click="
                                          (dialog.value = false),
                                            delQuo(item)
                                        "
                                        >Si</v-btn
                                      >
                                      <v-btn
                                        text
                                        @click="dialog.value = false"
                                        >No</v-btn
                                      >
                                    </v-card-actions>
                                  </v-card>
                                </template>
                              </v-dialog>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </v-card-text>
                      </v-col>
                    </v-responsive>
                  </v-card>
                </div>
```

hasta aqui he llegado... espero y me puedan orientar un poco

Comment: No entiendo realmente qué valores son los que quieres sumar y dónde necesitas el resultado Pero por ejemplo, con una [propiedad computada](https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Propiedades-Computadas) y el método [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) podrías sumar lo que necesitas y obtener el resultado en la propiedad computada.

Comment: los valors de precio que estan dentro de array que se llama details.. ya reviso las propiedad

Comment: Ah, para imprimirlo en el template, mientras hacer el loop, con un método vue en vez de una propiedad computada ya te alcanza.

Answer (score 0):

Con el método [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) de js podrías sumar lo que necesitas.

Puedes crearte un método vue para que te retorne el resultado, y llamarlo cuando haces el loop en el template, pasándole como argumento el array de objetos a sumar.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    tshit: [
        {
            "id":1,
            "selectRequi":[
                
            ]
        },
        {
            "id":2,
            "cotizaciones":[
                {
                    "Bodega":"xxxx",
                    "details":[
                    {
                        "Precio":"15.23",
                    },
                    {
                        "Precio":"50.33",
                    }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Bodega":"yyyy",
                    "details":[
                    {
                        "Precio":"15.23",
                    },
                    {
                        "Precio":"50.33",
                    }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
        ]
  },
  methods: {
    sumPrecios(items) {
      return items.reduce((a, b) => {
        return a + Number(b['Precio']);
    }, 0);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="example">
  <div v-for="(item, i) in tshit[1].cotizaciones" :key="i">
    Bodega: {{item.Bodega}}
    <p v-for="(child, index) in item.details" :key="index">
      Precio: {{ child.Precio }}
    </p>
    <p><strong>
      Suma: {{ sumPrecios(item.details) }}
    </strong></p>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```